# Impossible to deserialize a dependent transaction passed to an external API

Tags: c#, deserialization, transactionscope

I was trying to implement the example for DependentTransaction in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.dependenttransaction?view=netframework-4.8

The difference for me is that I pass the dependent transaction to an API and I am not able to restore the resulting object back into a DependentTransaction.

So here is the code:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    // code that saves an entity in the database within the above scope
    // code that creates an audit trail object
    object dependantTxn = Transaction.Current.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption.BlockCommitUntilComplete);
    AuditTrailParamterModel model = new AuditTrailParamterModel()
    {
       AuditTrail = auditTrail,
       transaction = dependantTxn
    }
    await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http//localhost/auditrail/api/InsertAuditTrail", model);
}
```

On the receiving end here is a portion of the code (like in the example):

```
[Route("api/InsertAuditTrail")]<br/>
[HttpPost]<br/>
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> InsertAuditTrail(AuditTrailParamterModel model)
{
    // Create a DependentTransaction from the object passed to API
    DependentTransaction dTx = (DependentTransaction)model.transation;

    // more code ....
}
```

The problem is that model.transation is populated with the following:

```
{{"OletxTransactionPropagationToken":"AQAAAAMAAADYbd5tQr4RbyxnSSp5UW2AAAQAAAAAABsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADk4NGNmZDU1LTQyMmUtNDI4MC04NDk3LTg2NjM3ODE4NjZjNQAAMAAHAAAAZM1kzSAAAABRTi0wMDMwABAAAABRAE4ALQAwADAAMwAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOAAAAdGlwOi8vUU4tMDAzMC8AAA=="}}
```

The line:

```
DependentTransaction dTx = (DependentTransaction)model.transation;
```

crashes.

The exception is

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Transactions.DependentTransaction'.

The type DependentTransaction inherits from Transaction and the members are as follows:

```
public static Transaction Current { get; set; }
public IsolationLevel IsolationLevel { get; }
public TransactionInformation TransactionInformation { get; }
public Guid PromoterType { get; }
```

and TransactionInformation has the following members:

```
public string LocalIdentifier { get; }
public Guid DistributedIdentifier { get; }
public DateTime CreationTime { get; }
public TransactionStatus Status { get; }
```

I also tried to see if I could use a decoder from Base64 format to see if that long string could be changed to a Transaction but it could not be done.

I have looked for hours online in order to find a solution to this and I can't find anything.

Can anyone help? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! (don't litter your whole post with crap  `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` tags.... totally unnecessary)

Comment: Thank you for helping with the formatting